# How to link checkbox and text value using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to clear text box when Checkbox is unchecked.

This is my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMinFixCharge" class="left" 
    data-bind="enable: isEnableMinFixedCharge,checked: isCheckMinFixedCharge" />

<input type="text" id="txtMinFixCharge" class="minitext left" 
    data-bind="value:?????" style="margin: 0px 10px;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line of code that help you

```
value:isCheckMinFixedCharge()? urdefinedVariable:''
```